# Quarkus Quit Kotlin index page is displaying io.quarkus.qute.runtime.TemplateProducer$InjectableTemplate$InjectableTemplateInstanceImp

Tags: kotlin, quarkus

I am using latest version of Quarkus with Kotlin and Qute.

I am trying to run my index page and when I call the page in browser I am keep getting white page with the below message. Look like the page is not rendering or the html file is not identified in templates folder.

**io.quarkus.qute.runtime.TemplateProducer$InjectableTemplate$InjectableTemplateInstanceImpl@581c8266**

Gradle properties

```
 quarkusPlatformArtifactId=quarkus-bom
 quarkusPlatformGroupId=io.quarkus.platform
 quarkusPlatformVersion=3.7.4
 quarkusPluginId=io.quarkus
```

gradle build file dependency

```
dependencies {
implementation("io.quarkus:quarkus-qute")
implementation(enforcedPlatform("${quarkusPlatformGroupId}:${quarkusPlatformArtifactId}:${quarkusPlatformVersion}"))
implementation("io.quarkus:quarkus-resteasy-jsonb")
implementation("io.quarkus:quarkus-kotlin")
implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
implementation("io.quarkus:quarkus-arc")
implementation("io.quarkus:quarkus-resteasy-reactive-jackson")
testImplementation("io.quarkus:quarkus-junit5")
testImplementation("io.rest-assured:rest-assured")
testImplementation("io.rest-assured:kotlin-extensions")
 }
```

the code is

```
 import io.quarkus.qute.Location
 import io.quarkus.qute.Template
 import io.quarkus.qute.TemplateInstance
 import jakarta.inject.Inject
 import jakarta.ws.rs.GET
 import jakarta.ws.rs.Path
 import jakarta.ws.rs.Produces
 import jakarta.ws.rs.core.MediaType


 @Path("/")
 @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
 class IndexEndpoint @Inject constructor(@Location("index/index.html") val index: Template) {

@GET
 fun index(): TemplateInstance {
   println("I am called.")
   return index.instance()
}

  }
```

I have a `base.html` in `templates` folder and   file in `index/index.html`   all have basic html content

Not sure what I am missing.